# Toasts in if and else are executed when else condition is true. Code first gives "signup successful" then it gives "user already exists"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On creating a new account, this code first gives `"signup successful"` then it gives "user already exists". Everything else is working fine.

Help me out with this. Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

also tried:

```
dataSnapshot.child(edtRoll.getText().toString())!=null
```

but it make the situation more worse, it always shows `"user doesn't exist"`.

```
btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (edtRoll.getText().toString().trim().length()!= 9)
            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Roll No. must have 9 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else if (edtName.getText().toString().trim().length() < 3)
            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Name is too short!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else if (edtPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() < 8)
            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Password must have atleast 8 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else if(!(edtPassword.getText().toString()).equals(edtConfirmPassword.getText().toString()))
            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Passwords do not match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {

            final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            mDialog.show();

            table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //Check if userRoll already exist
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(edtRoll.getText().toString()).exists()) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "User already registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        User user = new User(edtName.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString());
                        table_user.child(edtRoll.getText().toString()).setValue(user);
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Sign up Successfull!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is happened because whenever the button is clicked and user is in sign up state which giving `"signup successful"` , you're re-registering the listener for the data change:

```
btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
     if (...) {
      ...
     } else {
       table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         ...
       }
     }
   }
});
```

Hence you're receiving the `"signup successful"` then `"user already exists"` message.

You need to initialize the data change listener outside the click button method. Something like this:

```
final ProgressDialog mDialog;

private void initDataChangeListener() {

  table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
  });
}
```

Then call the initDataChangeListener before adding the click listener:

```
initDataChangeListener();

btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
     if (...) {
      ...
     } else {
       if(mDialog == null) mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);
       mDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
       mDialog.show();
       // no need to handle the data, because it's already handled by the data change listener.
     }
   }
});
```